# Windows 7, Ethernet NIC upload slow in normal, download always fast, Wi-Fi always fast

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, network-adapter

My laptop has a Wi-Fi and an Ethernet NIC. The Wi-Fi always has very good upload and download speeds (12 Mbps). The ethernet NIC always has very good download speeds (60 Mbps). However, the ethernet NIC in safe mode has upload speeds of about 60 Mbps in safe mode, and only 0.1 Mb/s in normal mode. This is the same for flash-based sites like speedtest.net, and non-flash sites like testmy.net. My configuration is:

- HP Pavillion M6-1035DX with AMD A-10
- Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit
- 16 GB RAM
- 1TB HDD (25% free)

I've done just about every recommended test I could find:

- Use msconfig to disable all startup items and disable every un-needed service
- Compare running procs and services between safe and normal mode and kill the extras in normal
- Uninstall the NIC driver and do fresh install
- Multiple virus scans using multiple vendors including CD-ROM booted tools
- Turned off AV (Sophos Endpoint)
- Disabled Windows Defender
- Disabled firewall

I have an identical laptop with the same Windows version that is OK. Could/should I compare registry keys? Which ones? Has anyone seen this? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the culprit was AMD QuickStream that has been on my system for a while. After I uninstalled and rebooted, uploads were back to normal. Perhaps an update of QuickStream or Windows broke it.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for sharing this. I've been trying to troubleshoot my neighbors laptop yesterday with similar issues and with no success so far. After installing some Windows updates a few days ago his network speed crawled to a halt too. I noticed Quickstream on his laptop too, but assumed (not having much AMD experience) it was a necessary part of the video-drivers. Will uninstall it when I get home tonight to see if that fixes the problem for him as well.

Comment: My neighbor is very happy that his laptop is downloading normally again :-) De-installing QuickStream and a reboot fixed it in his case too.